# CAN bus physical layer configuration for more than two devices

Tags: embedded, can, network-interface

I am designing a CAN bus for a light electric vehicle, likely using [an Arduino CAN bus shield](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10039) or similar.

Using a single D-sub cable it's obvious that two devices could be connected together. The system I'm designing will have multiple CAN nodes and so I'm curious of the best way to achieve this.

I think the best option is to use a simple D-sub splitter. This will keep the branch from the main CAN bus line less than 30 cm as per specifications and thus minimising interference.

The only other answer I can think of is to hack the board a little and wire up another connecter in parallel to the existing one.

Will using a simple splitter cause me any issues? If so, can I solve them?
If not, is there another easy way I can use these boards to interface with a CAN bus with multiple devices using D-sub cabling?

Comment: It all depends on the nature of the application. M12 connectors are more common for CAN, since dsubs are crappy and burdensome in rough environments, particularly when you have to go through cabinet walls or cable glands.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, yes. I'm assuming the splitters you have in mind only provide about 2 or 3 inches of split.